# Should I fill text/plain body when sending email?

Tags: c#, mimekit

When user registers in my system (web application), I want to send him an email with verification link so I can verify email address is correct and belongs to the user. Link will be shipped in text/html body version so user can directly click on it and open it in browser.

I just wondering should I fill a text/plain body too? Mimekit documentation [mentions](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Working-With-Messages.htm#MessageStructure) "The reason for sending the message text in both formats is that not all mail clients are capable of displaying HTML." but I suppose nowadays all modern mail clients should be able to support this.

I'm using c# and mimekit for sending emails.

My system targets enterprise customers, so some legacy systems should be kept in mind.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: I personally do think this particular question is appropriate for stackoverflow and does include sufficient information. However, you may have more luck on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ultimately, this is opinionated and that is the reason it should be closed. That said, I tend to a take a "why not" view on things like this. If it ends up helping one user, does it really save you that much time and energy to not do it. Here, the answer to that is a pretty big no. Just add the plain text version and move on with your day. In fact, you could have done it in the time it took to ask if you should.